# Gerrit doesn't pull in Administrators from Active Directory when using LDAP authentication?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, h2, gerrit

When using Active Directory LDAP authentication for Gerrit, Gerrit doesn't seem to be pulling in the users from the AD Administrators group ( =BIG problem :) ). Other users who are in the base directory for the dc and the Users container are being pulled in correctly once the group is created in Gerrit, but not users in the Administrators group, which is in the Builtin container in AD.

Here is my gerrit.config file:

```
...
    [auth]
        type=LDAP
    [ldap]
        server = ldap://ldapserver
        referral=follow
        username= user
        password= pass
        accountBase = dc=domain,dc=com
        groupBase = dc=domain,dc=com
        accountPattern = (&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=${username}))
        groupPattern = (&(objectClass=group)(cn=${groupname}))
        accountFullName = displayName
        accountMemberField = memberOf
        accountEmailAddress = mail
...
```

Anybody know a way to fix this? (even logging directly into the embedded DB somehow to stick in an admin, though I'm not sure about the login credentials used for that...)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not connecting via Gerritt as an admin, a basic user by default has only permissions to read one property set on members of protected groups (e.g. Admins). They must have access to the "General Information" property set here since you want to bring back the displayName attribute.

Comment: Indeed, it was enough to add the LDAP Gerrit user to the Administrators group and the other Administrators could be read/pulled into Gerrit.